# Gilab CI: load ssh key from environment variable

Tags: docker, ssh, openssl, gitlab-ci

I've spent the day trying to add a keypair to a docker image in Gitlab CI

I always get theses errors : "error in libcrypto" or "Invalid format" (depending on the docker image used), when loading the key in ssh-keygen to generate a pub key or in ssh-add when loading the private key :

> Load key "/root/.ssh/id_rsa": error in libcrypto

the code looks like :

```
job_deploy:
  image: ubuntu:kinetic
  stage: deploy
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push"
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "master"

  environment: "staging"
  before_script:
    - 'command -v ssh-agent >/dev/null || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client openssl libssl-dev -y )'
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
    # - echo -n "${SSH_PRIVATE_KEY}" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add - > /dev/null
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - echo "${SSH_PRIVATE_KEY}" > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    - chmod -R 400 ~/.ssh
    - ssh-keygen -y -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa > ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub # < error here
    # - ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa

  script:
    - ssh root@00.00.00.00 "ls"
```

The variable of the ssh key looks like this :

```
SSH_PRIVATE_KEY: "-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
b3BlbnNzaC1rZXktdjEAAAAABG5vbmUAAAAEbm9uZQAAAAAAAAABAAABlwAAAAdzc2gtcn
NhAAAAAwEAAQAAAYEAuNk4L4Cf4oDaDjXdjNydM6g5hg5/wGzxoqzENx2Xxq1QminyrZpB
...
Eo6Re1Rp+K3vifSALr2QbOfhd2yVy27oM8FuFQQpOppOJQPuWuwmSyHbT6AhIlAbo8E2v1
mrCMIVawQXSytHAAAAFmN5cHJpZW5AY3lwcmllbi11YnVudHUBAgME
-----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----"
```

I've tried adding a new line at the end of the variable

I've tried changing the docker image to a newer or older image of debian and ubuntu and the error remains

***error in libcrypto***

There is this issue in openssl for this error: https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/13443

but it's been solved in openssl-3.0.0-alpha16 and the error is present with openssl 3.0.3

Comment: Is SSH_PRIVATE_KEY defined inside Gitlab CI/CD variables?

Comment: It's defined in  .gitlab-ci-local-variables.yml since I'm using https://github.com/firecow/gitlab-ci-local to run the jobs locally. I can successfully echo the variable in the script

Comment: Does `.ssh/id_rsa` look like you expect it to?

Comment: I'm not sure, in fact it's echoing :  
  > -----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY----- b3BlbnNzaC1rZXktdjEAAAAABG5vbmUAAAAEbm9uZQAAAAAAAAABAAABlwAAAAdzc2gtcn NhAAAAAwEAAQAAAYEAuNk4L4Cf4oDaDjXdjNydM6g5hg5/wGzxoqzENx2Xxq1QminyrZpB DU3IevvG8D3xeNwNebdlXn48h34G0lQ6g2t3iF612pkWdJwkknzk2Y3c4T346NrvwbTGCQPZajU5h2/ZcE3jnFLZAvJZO1IxWURXL5AwWtIf/MKOT/aS7rPiKEXotqBCWsX65 Eo6Re1Rp+K3vifSALr2QbOfhd2yVy27oM8FuFQQpOppOJQPuWuwmSyHbT6AhIlAbo8E2v1 mrCMIVawQXSytHAAAAFmN5cHJpZW5AY3lwcmllbi11YnVudHUBAgME -----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
  > Load key "/root/.ssh/id_rsa": error in libcrypto

Comment: (truncated for SO), without newlines characters

Comment: But I’d guess it’s the log format of gitlab-ci-local that displays it without ne line characters. The contents of the file is the ssh key

Comment: I see you commented out a command to remove CR chars; if present in the envvar value particularly for the first line (or added to the last) that _would_ cause 'invalid format' in AFAICT all versions of OpenSSH. However, that doesn't explain 'error in libcrypto' which should only occur if (after) the format is parsed successfully.

Comment: I had a similar problem once, but my key was an `RSA PRIVATE KEY` -> `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` and when converted to `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----` everything was working fine

Comment: I removed the part ```OPENSSH```, It's not working

Comment: I'm having the same problem and have wasted HOURS trying to figure out what's going on. I reproduced the problem by creating an interactive Ubuntu Docker container, installing the `ssh-client` apt package, and attempting to SSH from the container.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the solution I found :

```
  before_script:
    - 'command -v ssh-agent >/dev/null || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client wget gnupg -y )'
    - wget -qO- https://get.docker.com/gpg | apt-key add -
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
    - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add -
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - touch ~/.ssh/config
    - touch ~/.ssh/known_hosts
    - chmod -R 400 ~/.ssh
    - ssh-keyscan <ip> >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
    - '[[ -f /.dockerinit ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config'
```

create a variable SSH_PRIVATE_KEY with the content of your key (add an empty line at the end)

That being said, I could'nt make it work with a runner running on my development machine.

Comment: For those wondering, it's the `tr -d '\r'` that helps here, as in some contexts GitLab may use `\r\n` instead of `\n` to separate variables lines.

Comment: The empty final line in the GitLab variables for ID_RSA and SSH_PRIVATE_KEY was the issue in my case.